# Hyperlink that Opens into Portrait Formatted Window With Specific Dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, portrait

[image]

This page has to open up in Portrait format with the dimensions 400 x 350 (px). I'm not sure if I need to use javascript or CSS to achieve this, but this is what I tried:

link from "index.html" that links to the new page, "form.html":

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="form.html">Request
Information</a>
```

HTML for "form.html":

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sean's Hardware Store</title>
<script src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>
<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align=right bgcolor=#ffffff>
<img src="logo.jpg"><br>
<font face=arial></font>    </td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<center>
<table width=85%>
<tr>
<td valign=top>
<form method=post action="">
    Name:<br>
<input name="textname" size=35><br><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input name="textname" size=35>
<br><br>
<input type=submit name="button1" value="Submit">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("window").onchange=function() {
  window.open("","newWin","width=400,height=350");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
    },100);// allow IE to get over the shock of opening a window
  }
}
```

Also, can index and form be linked to the same javascript file? Right now I have two separate js files because I don't want them to interfere with one another (index also has some js). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it straight from your HTML like this:

```
<a href="form.html" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
'toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,
resizable=yes,width=400, height=350');
return false;">Request Information</a>
```